# Kibana Inspect - Access via java script

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, kibana

I need to access the elastic search query from the graph panels of kibana dashboard.

Is there any possibility of accessing the contents of inspect element via javascript?

Thanks,
Chandan

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you well, than this is standard functionality of kibana. In the image below check the red arrow. Just push the i button and you will be presented with the query that is used to create the panel.

[image]

Comment: Hi @JettroCoenradie,
Yes. We can access the elastic search query manually. But since we don't have the export to pdf/print option for the graph, I was trying to add this custom functionality. For this I need to access the query on the fly, considering any dynamic filters applied. I am looking for ways to access the elastic search query via java script or some other means.

Comment: In the end everything is stored in the index but abstracting the query of a specific widget is not easy. You can check the dashboard document in the .kibana index.